# SQL Select exact matches from Many to Many Table

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

Given a SQL table relating Orders and Products.

```
CREATE TABLE Order_Product(
  unid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  order_id INT NOT NULL,
  product_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDb AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How to decide whether an Order with a specific list of Products (only specified products, not more or less)  is present in the database ?
My current SQL query combines two tables, first table to check which Orders contain the products (e.g. 34,48) and the second to search whether the Order does not contain more products.

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT COUNT(op.order_id) hits, op.order_id
    FROM Order_Product op
    WHERE op.product_id IN (34,48)
    GROUP BY op.order_id 
    HAVING COUNT(op.order_id ) = 2

) AS tabone
JOIN  ( SELECT COUNT(op.order_id) total, op.order_id
    FROM Order_Product op
    GROUP BY op.order_id
       ) AS tabtwo
ON tabtwo.order_id = tabone.order_id
WHERE hits = total
```

Can you imagine a more simple way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I'm assuming you are looking for orders containing at least one product from the list and not all the products in the list):

```
select *
from Order_Product as op1
where exists (
    select 1
    from Order_Product as op2
    where op2.order_id = op1.order_id
    and op2.product_id in (34, 38)
    )
and not exists (
    select 1
    from Order_Product as op3
    where op3.order_id = op1.order_id
    and op3.product_id not in (34, 38)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your questions sounds like you want all orders that must contain both products 34 and 48 but no more and no less.

```
SELECT op1.Order_ID
FROM Order_Product op1
JOIN (SELECT Order_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT Product_ID) AS Total_Products FROM Order_Product GROUP BY Order_ID) op2 
  ON op1.Order_ID = op2.Order_ID
WHERE op1.product_id IN (34, 48)
AND op2.Total_Products = 2
GROUP BY op1.Order_ID
```